# Powershell equivalent of devcon.exe

Tags: powershell

I'm trying to convert this windows .BAT file  into Powershell. so if there is someone who could give me the powershell version of what I need to do would be much appreciated.

Batch File :

```
for /f "delims=:" %%x in ('%SystemRoot%\Setup\Scripts\NIC_Fix\devcon.exe findall *dev_07B0*') do %SystemRoot%\Setup\Scripts\NIC_Fix\devcon.exe remove "@%%x"
%SystemRoot%\Setup\Scripts\NIC_Fix\devcon.exe rescan
```

Kind regards,

Comment: Calling an exe works exactly the same in powershell as in a batch script.

Answer (score 0):

I found something like this somewhere.  It's powershell and at least pnputil comes with windows.

```
# dell2020vidfix.ps1

# Get-PnpDevice -PresentOnly -Status ERROR,DEGRADED,UNKNOWN

foreach ($dev in Get-PnpDevice -FriendlyName '*Intel(R) UHD Graphics 630*') {
  pnputil /remove-device $dev.InstanceId }
pnputil /scan-devices
```

```
Microsoft PnP Utility

Removing device:       PCI\VEN_8086&DEV_3E92&SUBSYS_09361028&REV_00\3&11583659&8&10
Device removed successfully.

Microsoft PnP Utility

Scanning for device hardware changes.
Scan complete.
```